# How to create an ENUM with a "new" value in Java?

Tags: java, enums

How I can add `new` as a value to an enum in Java?

Here's my enum:

```java
public enum AgentProspectStatus 
{
    loose("loose"),
    on_progress("on_progress"),
    reached("reached"),
    alumni("alumni"),
    student("student"),
    new("new"); // This throws an error

    private String code;
    AgentProspectStatus(String code) 
    {
         this.code = code;
    }
}
```

The `new("new")` line is showing the error:

> Unexpected Token

Comment: "new" is a reserved word. It will work if you rename the enum, such as to `newbie("new")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`new` is [keyword in Java](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords). In Java, enums should be spelled in uppercase and case_snake. Changing the case will fix your error.

```
public enum AgentProspectStatus {
            LOOSE("loose"),
            ON_PROGRESS("on_progress"),
            REACHED("reached"),
            ALUMNI("alumni"),
            STUDENT("student"),
            NEW("new");

            private String code;
            AgentProspectStatus(String code) {
                this.code = code;
            }
        }
```

Comment: a list of all keywords can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Java_keywords